# Table not fully displayed

Tags: php, mysql, css

I have used datepicker function from jquery (one as startdate and another as enddate) and using it to get the date from the user & querying mysql database.

When user enters startdate for eg. 25 Aug and enddate 26 Aug, table outputs only 24 rows (mixed of 25th & 26th), which should be actually 48 rows hour wise. How to fix ?

```
<script>
        $( function(){
        $("#startdate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yymmdd'});
        } );

        $( function(){
        $("#enddate").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yymmdd'});
        } );
</script>


<?php
  $connect = new mysqli("x.x.x.x","acacacac","acacacac","acacacac");
  $startdate=$_POST['startdate'];
  $enddate=$_POST['enddate'];
  $ingress=$_POST['ingress'];
  $sql="SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(ingress_call_info_inviting_ts,'%Y-%m-%d %H') AS Hourly,
        ingress_call_info_zone_name as Ingress,
        Count(cat.id) AS Attempts
        FROM asas
        WHERE 
        ingress_call_info_inviting_ts BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' AND
        ingress_call_info_zone_name LIKE '$ingress'
        GROUP BY TIME_FORMAT(ingress_call_info_inviting_ts,'%H:00')
        ORDER BY TIME_FORMAT(ingress_call_info_inviting_ts,'%H:00')";
        $records=$connect->query($sql);
?>

<?php
while ($report=$records->fetch_assoc()) {      
echo "<tr>";
?><td style="border:1px solid black; text-align: center;>"<?php
echo "<td border='1'>".$report['Hourly']."</td>";
?><td style="border:1px solid black; text-align: center;>"<?php
echo "<td border='1'>".$report['Ingress']."</td>";
?><td style="border:1px solid black; text-align: center;>"<?php
echo "<td border='1'>".$report['Attempts']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";       
}
?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no time in `$startdate` and `$enddate`, it uses `00:00:00` as the time. Any times on the `$enddate` that are after `00:00:00` won't be included. You can use

```
WHERE DATE(ingress_call_inviting_ts) BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate'
```

but this won't be able to use an index on the column, so it may be slow. You can also add the time of the end of the date to `$enddate`.

```
WHERE ingress_call_info_inviting_ts BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '{$enddate}235959'
```

Comment: You are right about the time format. The date-time column in my database has 'YYMMDDHHmmSSxxxx'. I am getting the output in the table, no problem with that, but if the date has a difference of 2 days, data shows random from two days (fixed of 24 rows) but as i am filtering hour wise it should have shown 48 rows (as 2 days has 48 hours).

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? Is it `DATETIME` or `VARCHAR`?

Comment: datatype is datetime. I am also sure that no problem with mysql query, as i have used the same query in other 3rd party software like Navicat. Having problem while doing it in php.

Comment: I don't see how it can be selecting randomly from the two days. I think it should be finding all the hours in the first day, and nothing from the second day. Also, you won't get any rows for hours that have no rows in them.